# Div is not being placed next to each other

Tags: html, css

Essentially I have some text message bubbles. I want to put in the date and time next to the bubbles (respectively) but they don't seem to be placed in the right place. As you can see the blue text bubble has the date displayed on the right hand side of the bubble and the grey bubble has text displayed on the left hand side of the bubble.

**How I want it to look**

[image: How I want it to look]

**How it actually looks**

[image: How it actually looks]

Could someone please help me with this. I am very confused

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
.chat {
  width: 320px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0.5em 0em;
}

.them-bubble {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  background: #e5e5ea;
  max-width: 75%;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.them-bubble::after  {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.5em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 1em;
  border-right: 0.5em solid #e5e5ea;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em 0.5em;
}

.me-bubble {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  max-width: 75%;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  float: right;
  background-color: #1289fe;
  color: white;
}

.me-bubble::after  {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -0.5em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 1em;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #1289fe;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em 0.5em;
}

.me-date {
    color: #98979c;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 65px;
    float: right;
}

.them-date {
    color: #98979c;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 65px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">

    <div class="message">
        <div class="me-date">22/11/19 11:42 PM</div>
        <div class="me-bubble">
            <p>Hello how are you</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
        <div class="them-date">22/11/19 11:43 PM</div>
        <div class="them-bubble">
            <p>I am good, how are you?</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
        <div class="me-date">22/11/19 11:44 PM</div>
        <div class="me-bubble">
            <p>I am fantastic. This is a long message so the bubble goes down into another couple lines. Typing more text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
        <div class="them-date">22/11/19 11:43 PM</div>
        <div class="them-bubble">
            <p>This is a really long reply so the messahe makes multiple bubbles. More typing here</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
        <div class="them-date">22/11/19 11:46 PM</div>
        <div class="them-bubble">
            <p>Double sending them message</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="message">
        <div class="them-date">22/11/19 11:46 PM</div>
        <div class="them-bubble">
            <p>Triple sending them message and this is a double long bubble</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your issue is with the floats. Remove the (two) floats and you will have a better understanding. No need to use flexbox or rearrange your structure. Absolute positioning might play here, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With flexbox and five style rules, you can create this effect:

```css
/* New Code */

.message {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.message .me-date {
  order: 2;
}

.message .me-bubble {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.message .me-date {
  text-align: right;
}

.message .me-bubble,
.message .them-bubble {
  max-width: 200px;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
.chat {
  width: 320px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0.5em 0em;
}

.them-bubble {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  background: #e5e5ea;
  max-width: 75%;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.them-bubble::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.5em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 1em;
  border-right: 0.5em solid #e5e5ea;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em 0.5em;
}

.me-bubble {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  max-width: 75%;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  float: right;
  background-color: #1289fe;
  color: white;
}

.me-bubble::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -0.5em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 1em;
  border-left: 0.5em solid #1289fe;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em 0.5em;
}

.me-date {
  color: #98979c;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 65px;
}

.them-date {
  color: #98979c;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 65px;
}

.chat {
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">

  <div class="message">
    <div class="me-date">22/11/19 11:42 PM</div>
    <div class="me-bubble">
      <p>Hello how are you</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="message">
    <div class="them-date">22/11/19 11:43 PM</div>
    <div class="them-bubble">
      <p>I am good, how are you?</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="message">
    <div class="me-date">22/11/19 11:44 PM</div>
    <div class="me-bubble">
      <p>I am fantastic. This is a long message so the bubble goes down into another couple lines. Typing more text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="message">
    <div class="them-date">22/11/19 11:43 PM</div>
    <div class="them-bubble">
      <p>This is a really long reply so the messahe makes multiple bubbles. More typing here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="message">
    <div class="them-date">22/11/19 11:46 PM</div>
    <div class="them-bubble">
      <p>Double sending them message</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="message">
    <div class="them-date">22/11/19 11:46 PM</div>
    <div class="them-bubble">
      <p>Triple sending them message and this is a double long bubble</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You've used `message:nth-child(odd)` which means its essentially changing the direction of the message each time. What if someone there is 3 `them-bubbles` one after the other? Not familiar with flex. Updated the HTML code in first post

Comment: @Jackie are you stuck with this HTML structure? It would be better if the me/them class was on the `.message` div

Comment: No I am not stuck with this HTML structure. I thought this is how you are supposed to do it. Everything is changeable. There is no set code structure

Comment: @Jackie it would be slightly easier if the `.message` divs were `class="message me"` and `class="message them"`. Then you can just use `date` and `bubble` inside them. In any event, I fixed the CSS in my answer to use the structure you have now.

Comment: Wait you can have 2 classes? If you have 2 classes, does it mean, it inherits both attributes?

Comment: @Jackie you can have as many classes as you want, yeah. Then any child elements can be referenced by one or both parents, e.g. `.message .date`, `.me .date`, or `.message.me .date`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203791/discussion-between-symlink-and-jackie).